# Formtastic label_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

Can you use two values in a Formtastic label_method?

This:

```
<%= f.input :isbn_id, :label_method => :name, :as => :select, :collection => Isbn.order("name ASC").where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).all %>
```

produces this drop down menu:

```
Adept
Adept
Red Men
Red Men
Blue Handbag
```

But I'd like this:

```
Adept pbk
Adept hb
Red Men pbk
Red Men hb
Blue Handbag hb
```

So I'd like this to work:

```
<%= f.input :isbn_id, :label_method => "#{:name} #{:format}", :as => :select, :collection => Isbn.order("name ASC").where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).all %>
```

But of course it doesn't.

Comment: I think I'll go boil my head. Thanks, that's great. (If you put it in an answer, I'll tick it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you add a method to your model say `formatted_name` that returns the string `"#{name} #{format}"` and call at the formtastic helper `:label_method => :formatted_name` ??